# How to rename a chef cookbook?

Tags: chef-infra

I was wondering if there is a better way to rename a cookbook than the obvious and painful option. We have close 100 CBs and we want to apply a new naming convention. Just checking before start working on some custom solution.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Nothing specific, there are `knife exec` transform scripts floating around the cargo cult that handles run list fixups but that's usually the least of your worries. If you don't care about old versions, wipe them all and re-upload?

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer, my first thought was writing a script to rename the cookbook, I guess I should take that route. I will post the final solution here.